# Vertica console not displaying graphs, logs indicate invalid authentication credentials

Tags: vertica

Setup: 10-node cluster running Vertica 7.2.3 on Ubuntu 14.04

I'm running into a problem with our live Vertica management console regarding authentication. The graphs, etc. are not displaying, saying "unable to retrieve chart data", and I see tons of messages in the logs about "invalid username or password", e.g.

> 23 Jul 2018 11:29:01,599 [qtp757411119-120 - /webui/databases/1/chartdata/quick-stat-query-processing?cache_buster1532370541102] DatabaseConnectionPoolService WARN - ValidateConnection failed: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([Vertica]VJDBC FATAL: Invalid username or password), SQL State Code: 28000, Error Code: 3781

Initially I noticed that 4 of the 10 nodes were not showing properly in the console but ultimately that just required restarting the Vertica agent

I've ensured the SUPER dbadmin account credentials are correct and the database is otherwise ok. I'm considering trying a [factory reset](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ManagementConsole/TroubleshootingMC/ResettingMCToPre-configuredState.htm%3FTocPath%3DUsing%2520Management%2520Console%7CTroubleshooting%2520with%2520MC%25C2%25A0Diagnostics%7C_____4) of the console but I'm wary of doing so since I've never done that.

Any thoughts on where the specific problem may lie?